# Pandas read_csv - dealing with columns that have ID numbers with consecutive '$' and '#' symbols, along with letters and digits

Tags: string, csv, symbols, dtype

I'm trying to read a csv file with a column of data that has a scrambled ID number that includes the occasional consecutive $$ along with #, numbers, and letters.

| SCRAMBLE_ID |
| --- |
| AL9LLL677 |
| AL9$AM657 |
| $L9$$4440 |
| #L9$306A1 |

etc.

I tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MASTER~1.CSV',
                 dtype = {'SCRAMBLE_ID': str})
```

which rendered the third entry as *L9*$4440 (L9 appear in serif font, italicized, and the first and second $ vanish).

Faced with an entire column of ID numbers configured in this manner, what is the best way of dealing with such data?  I can imagine:

1. PRIOR TO pd.read_csv: replacing the offending symbols with substitutes that don't create this problem (and what would those be), OR,
2. is there a way of preserving the IDs as is but making them into a data type that ignores these symbols while keeping them present?

Thank you. I've attached a screenshot of the .csv side by side with resulting df (Jupyter notebook) below.
[csv column to pandas df with $$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ohi3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate this using the same values as you in a mock CSV file.

Are you sure that the formatting based on the $ symbol is not occurring in wherever you are rendering your dataframe values? Have you checked to see if the data in the dataframe is what you expect or are you just rendering it externally?

Comment: Apologies, Ben--I don't quite understand what rendering externally is.  I took a look at the .csv file in excel, and then compared it side by side with df.head() after using pd.read_csv as above, and the dollar signs bracketing 'L9' in the third row vanish in the pandas df, leaving just the single $ before '4440'.  The column of values in the .csv file has no special formatting.

Comment: Are you doing this in a shell? How are you executing your code? Jupyter notebook? When I create a dataframe using the same values and dtype as you, my dataframe has the correct data inside it,

Comment: Yes, it's in a Jupyter notebook. Attached a side-by-side screenshot to the original post above.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Jupyter uses MathJax which means it will render a character between dollar signs as italics. You could either look into disabling this in Jupyter notebook, or you could put a backslash character before your dollar signs. Either way, the data in the frame is actually correct right now, Jupyter is just rendering it in this odd way for you. I think you can turn off this rendering by having a line pd.options.display.html.use_mathjax = False but I have not tested this.

Comment: Wow.  Perhaps I need to just move into PyCharm, but I'll see if I can disable that rendering.  THANKS BENJAMIN!